# send the data typed in TextBox to a web Service URL

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get the value from a textBox in C#,to put the value in a Web Service URL,but the problem is that I get always an empty value:

```
 private async void searchlocal_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UriString1 = "MyURL"+searchlocal.Text;

            var http = new HttpClient();
            http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriString1);
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
            sponsorname.Text = rootObject.one_searchs[0].nom;
        }
```

this is the definition of the TextBox in the designer:

```
<TextBox x:Name="searchlocal" PlaceholderText="Adress"  KeyDown="searchlocal_KeyDown" />
```

Is there any method that I can call it to send the data taped in the TextBox to the web service URL?

Comment: is KeyDown the right method in my case??

Comment: You  should subscribe to TextChanged event instead of KeyDown as KeyDown will not add the text immediately in Text property.

Comment: thanks  user1672994 for your reply,but I didn't get the all text in the TextBox I get only the first letter :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subscribe to `TextChanged` Event which occurs when the Text property value changes of `TextBox`.

```
private async void searchlocal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

<TextBox x:Name="searchlocal" PlaceholderText="Adress"  TextChanged="searchlocal_TextChanged" />
```

Comment: thanks user1672994 for your reply,but I didn't get the all text in the TextBox I get only the first letter